# How can I embed a Dublin Core XML file into a TIFF using XMP?

Tags: metadata, tiff, xmp, dublin-core

I work in an archive and as we scan photos, we'd like to embed them with metadata rather than use sidecar metadata.  I'm tired of using IPTC, especially since I've always used (and most archivists use) DC for the tag set.  It's just more universally known.  How can I embed an XML of DC metadata into a TIFF using XMP?

I've downloaded the XMP ToolKit and I'm worried that it might be over my head.  I have some light Python experience, but that's it.  There's got to be an easier way to embed the XML into the TIFF tag for XMP.  With IPTC, I was able to use the Cultural Heritage Panel that gives a nice UI for entering it.  It's just not the type of metadata we need.

Comment: I think ExifTool should be able to do it, have a look at [this page](https://ninedegreesbelow.com/photography/exiftool-commands.html). You may need to transform your DC XML into XMP first, though.